# How can I do standalone/offline validation of HTML+WAI-ARIA documents?

Tags: html, validation, w3c-validation, wai-aria

Testing WAI-ARIA validation on the new [HTML5 validation page](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) from w3.org is helpful, but how can I do standalone validation without an Internet connection?

CI integration comes to mind; so also, how can I get plain-text output (rather than HTML output) that can be parsed later on or at least stored by Jenkins?

Comment: How about a tool like [WAVE by WebAIM](http://wave.webaim.org/)? It will help you with ARIA and accessibility in general, and it is available as a plugin for Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: This question and its answer would be a good fit for [softwarerecs.se] (while it’s likely off-topic here on SO). I don’t know if the SO mods would migrate to a Beta site, but you may ask them by flagging your question.

Comment: Agreed, the question as originally written was off-topic for SO. So I rewrote my answer to instead be an on-topic **Here’s how to do it…** response, and I took the liberty of re-wording the question to be an actual on-topic one for SO; that is, along the lines of, *Here’s a problem I need to solve; how do a I solve it?*—Where the problem the OP wants to solve is (1) how to check HTML documents for WAI-ARIA conformance from the command line, and (2) more specifically, how to get the results in a format that can be consumed by Jenkins or other CI automation tools.

Comment: I think the edits that I made to the question have brought it into being on-topic, and I think my answer is also on-topic and focused on helping the OP solve specific problems. So while I agree 100% with @unor that a similar question might also be a good fit for [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), I think that as its now (re)worded, the question is also a good fit for SO. So I’d like to request that the moderators consider clearing the hold after reviewing my changes.

Answer (score 3):

Here’s how to use the standalone [Nu Html Checker](https://github.com/validator/validator/) to check files from the command line:

```
java -jar ~/vnu.jar FILE.html FILE2.html FILE3.HTML FILE4.html...
```

By default the results are emitted as plain text, with one line for each error or warning, in the [standard GNU error format](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Errors), with the filename, line+column number, and the actual error/warning message; so, each line from the results you get will be in this format:

```
"FILE.HTML":76.1-76.23: info warning: Section lacks heading. Consider using “h2”-“h6” elements to add identifying headings to all sections.
```

Many existing tools (e.g., `gcc` and other compilers, emacs, etc.) have built-in support for consuming error output in that format, so it should be relatively easy to plug into your Jenkins or Travis or other CI setup—or into whatever pipeline you want to use.

But you can also [get output as JSON or XML](https://validator.github.io/validator/#format) if you want; detailed  info on how to use the tool is at https://validator.github.io/validator/#usage. Further, there are packages that take the standalone checker and wrap specific frontends around it for use as plugins for commonly-used task runners:

- [`grunt-html`—Grunt plugin for HTML checking](https://github.com/jzaefferer/grunt-html)
- [`gulp-html`—Gulp plugin for HTML checking](https://github.com/watilde/gulp-html)

---

#### More details

The standalone HTML checker is exactly the same code as the W3C validator, but packaged as an runnable jar; so you can integrate it into  CI automation, and batch-check multiple files at once, or walk entire directory trees, and you can write scripts that call it and do things with its output.

The latest is always available in the following places:

- https://github.com/validator/validator/releases/latest
- https://sideshowbarker.net/releases/jar/

**Full disclosure:**: I’m the developer of this standalone version of the checker, and I'm a co-developer of the [core code it uses](https://github.com/validator/validator/) [as well as being the maintainer of the online W3C HTML Checker (*aka* validator) service]. So I very much welcome [bug reports and feature requests](https://github.com/validator/validator/issues/new).